# Is Soul Calibur V available on PS4?

Tags: ps4, soul-calibur-5

Is there any way of getting Soul Calibur V on PS4? Or do I have to buy the PS3 game and then pay to convert it (how would that work)?

Answer (score 2):

No, Soul Caliber V is not available on the PS4, only the PS3. You can't typically transfer games from PS3 to PS4, but in some cases buying one version entitles you to another console's version (these will be marked with a cross-platform/cross-buy icon and mention it in the description somewhere). In this case, there just isn't a PS4 port of the game, so there isn't a way to play it on PS4.

It's worth mentioning that Soul Caliber V was [announced for the PS Now service](http://www.fightinggamer.co.za/news/9075-soulcalibur-v-and-ii-hd-coming-to-playstation-now) in mid-2016, but it was for Japan only.

Comment: Thanks man, shame about living in the UK for me. Might need to invest in the past

Comment: @JB no problem, sorry there's not a way to play on PS4! If this answered you question, please make sure to mark the check mark to let others know this helped you.